# Не могу понять, почему возникает TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для функции `input()` используется перенаправление ввода из файла.
Через `input()` получаем строку типа `one Two Three`

```
a=input().lower().split()
d=dict()
 for i in a:
    if a[i] in d:
        d[i]+=1
    else:
        d.setdefault(a[i],[1])
```

Ошибка:

```
if a[i] in d:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: А конечная цель задачи какова? Если, как я полагаю посчитать количество вхождений каждого слова, то посмотрите `Counter` из `collections`

Answer (score 4):

Вы используете в качестве индекса строковую переменную, что не допустимо:
`for i in a:` Вернет элементы списка а не их индексы.
Для того, чтобы использовать индексы цикл `for` должен иметь следующий вид:
`for i in range(len(a)):`
Соответственно Ваш код будет выглядеть так, **но работать не будет**:

```
a = input().lower().split()
d = dict()
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in d:
        d[i] += 1
    else:
        d.setdefault(a[i], [1])
```

Не знаю что требуется в задаче но имхо можно так.

```
a = input().lower().split()
d = dict()
for item in a:
    d[item] = d.get(item, 0) + 1
```

Поясню. Метод `get()` словаря возвращает значение по ключу словаря, если ключ есть в словаре или заданное значение (по умолчанию None), если ключ в словаре отсутствует.

#### Решение с `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(input().lower().split())
```

Comment: Как же я был глуп

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев. Добавил решение с Counter, как мне кажется это то, что нужно.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Можно добавить, что если вам нужно получить и индексы, и значение списка по индексу, то можно использовать `enumerate`: `for i, c in enumerate(a):`